# How to Query from database joined tables and use between of dates or range?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a two tables in my database i want join them and use between or range in the dates from another table how do i do that in SQL.

My Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM userdetails 
RIGHT JOIN returndocs on returndocs.EmailAddress = userdetails.EmailAddress 
WHERE DateSubmitted BETWEEN '2020-01-05' and '2020-02-10'
```

I want to select all the data in table `userdetails` and join `returndocs` table which contains from information by filtering the `DateSubmitted` in table `returndocs`. If i use this query its returning all data from table `returndocs` and `userdetails` table will be empty. Below are the results from the query.

[image: Results from the query are here]

Comment: Try `SELECT * 
FROM userdetails 
LEFT JOIN returndocs ON returndocs.EmailAddress = userdetails.EmailAddress 
AND returndocs.DateSubmitted BETWEEN '2020-01-05' and '2020-02-10'`

Comment: @Akina, its now vice versa the returndocs table is now the one which is returning null values

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some sample data, and show desired result for this sample data, please. Excess field unrelated to the main goal may be removed of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You woudl seem to want a `LEFT JOIN` starting with `userdetails`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userdetails ud LEFT JOIN
     returndocs rd
     ON rd.EmailAddress = ud.EmailAddress AND
        rd.DateSubmitted BETWEEN '2020-01-05' AND '2020-02-10' ;
```

Note that the condition on `DateSubmitted` needs to be in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `WHERE` would change the outer join to an inner join by filtering out unmatched values.

I would recommend writing the `datesubmitted` condition as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userdetails ud LEFT JOIN
     returndocs rd
     ON rd.EmailAddress = ud.EmailAddress AND
        rd.DateSubmitted >= '2020-01-05' AND 
        rd.DateSubmitted < '2020-02-11' ;
```

This will work even if the `DateSubmitted` has a time component.